# Summarising across multiple vars with dplyr

Tags: ggplot2

I have a dataset that has multiple categorical vars and several groups. I want to plot these vars in a second step, but first I want to summarize these categorical vars.

Thank you!

```
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Species) %>%
  mutate(sep5=ifelse(Sepal.Length>5,">5","<5"),wid5=ifelse(Sepal.Width>3,">3","<3")) %>%
  group_by(Species,sep5) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>% ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    sep5      n   pct
  <fct>      <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 setosa     <5       28  0.56
2 setosa     >5       22  0.44
3 versicolor <5        3  0.06
4 versicolor >5       47  0.94
5 virginica  <5        1  0.02
6 virginica  >5       49  0.98
```

I then plot it

```
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Species) %>%
  mutate(sep5=ifelse(Sepal.Length>5,">5","<5"),wid5=ifelse(Sepal.Width>3,">3","<3")) %>%
  group_by(Species,sep5) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>% ungroup()%>%
ggplot(data=.,
       aes(x=Species,group=sep5,y=pct,fill=sep5))+geom_col(position="dodge")
```

[image]

Great , but I actually want to know if there are statistically significant differences between species.

```
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Species) %>%
  mutate(sep5=ifelse(Sepal.Length>5,">5","<5"),wid5=ifelse(Sepal.Width>3,">3","<3")) %>%
  group_by(Species,sep5) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>% filter(sep5=="<5")%>%
  ggplot(data=.,
         aes(x=Species,group=sep5,y=pct,fill=sep5))+geom_col(position="dodge")
```

This removes those whoe are >5 and leaves those others which creates a plot that fits my needs.

However, I would like to be able to add a ggsignif::geom_signif, that compares between groups (which is probably not possible, after having removed the sep5.

If I don't remove the sep5 and just add geom_signif, I get an error.

```
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Species) %>%
  mutate(sep5=ifelse(Sepal.Length>5,">5","<5"),wid5=ifelse(Sepal.Width>3,">3","<3")) %>%
  group_by(Species,sep5) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) -> plot_data

  ggplot(plot_data,aes(x=Species,group=sep5,y=pct,fill=sep5))+geom_col(position="dodge") +
  ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons=list("setosa","versicolor"),
                        test="chisq.test")
```

If I change from percent to n, still no luck.

```
  ggplot(plot_data,aes(x=Species,group=sep5,fill=sep5,y=n))+
    geom_col(position="dodge") +
  ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons=list("setosa","versicolor"),
                        test="chisq.test")

Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_signif()`.
Caused by error:
! 'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

Ideally, it should only plot those which fulfill a binary categorical var (>5 for example) and then compare these differences for statstical significane on the plot.

I have gotten a workaround to work , which creates a seperate tibble and then passes that onto a chisq-test function , which I could then use to draw these labels again but I thought, that there must be an easier / more straighforward solution.